# SQL server: How to count maximum consercutive change for each observation in

Tags: sql-server, cursor, window, fetch, aggregate-functions

I'd used sql server 2012. I want to count maximum consecutive change for each obs. The table like this

```html
snapshot_date customer_id Number Max_consercutive_increase_as_of_each_row
Jan-14 12342 0 0
Feb-14 12342 15 1
Mar-14 12342 45 2
Apr-14 12342 0 2
May-14 12342 15 2
Jun-14 12342 45 2
Jul-14 12342 75 3
Aug-14 12342 105 4
Sep-14 12342 135 5
Oct-14 12342 0 4
Nov-14 12342 0 3
Dec-14 12342 0 2
Jan-15 12342 0 1
Feb-15 12342 0 0
Mar-15 12342 0 0
Apr-15 12342 0 0
```

[image]

As of each rows, count backward to 06 preceding rows (include current row). Of course, some starting rows only 01 or 02 rows before. Increasing based on 'number' column. In 06 rows, if max consecutive between 2 and 3 --> i want take 3.

I try to use cursor with fetch relative -n rows, but my code is not working.
So please help me to resolve it.

Thanks so much!

Comment: can you post your script till now how you had Tried.

Comment: I'd tried use cursor with fetch relative like:                                                      fetch relative -5 from Test1cursor into ...
fetch relative -5 from Test1cursor into ...
end

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
-- Create test data

declare @t table(snapshot_date date,customer_id int,Number int);
insert into @t values ('20140101',12342,    0   ),('20140201',12342,    15  ),('20140301',12342,    45  ),('20140401',12342,    0   ),('20140501',12342,    15  ),('20140601',12342,    45  ),('20140701',12342,    75  ),('20140801',12342,    105 ),('20140901',12342,    135 ),('20141001',12342,    0   ),('20141101',12342,    0   ),('20141201',12342,    0   ),('20150101',12342,    0   ),('20150201',12342,    0   ),('20150301',12342,    0   ),('20150401',12342,    0   );

with d as    -- Add a row number to the dataset
(
    select snapshot_date
            ,customer_id
            ,Number
            ,row_number() over (order by snapshot_date) as rn
    from @t
)
,c as        -- Use a recursive CTE to loop through the dataset and check for increases
(
    select snapshot_date
            ,customer_id
            ,Number
            ,rn
            ,0 as ConsecutiveIncreases
    from d
    where rn = 1

    union all

    select t.snapshot_date
            ,t.customer_id
            ,t.Number
            ,t.rn
            ,case when t.Number > c.Number then c.ConsecutiveIncreases + 1 else 0 end
    from d as t
        join c
            on t.rn = c.rn+1
)
-- Take the MAX consecutive increase where the current row is also an increase,
-- unless the row is not an increase, then subtract the number of non-increases
-- from the MAX consecutive increase to find the number of increases within the last 6 rows.
-- If less than 6 rows to use, just take the MAX increase.
select c.snapshot_date
        ,c.customer_id
        ,c.Number
        ,case when isnull(sum(c2.ConsecutiveIncreases),0) = 0
                then 0
              when count(c2.ConsecutiveIncreases) < 6
                then max(c2.ConsecutiveIncreases)
              else max(c2.ConsecutiveIncreases) - case when c.ConsecutiveIncreases = 0
                                                       then sum(case when c2.ConsecutiveIncreases = 0
                                                                     then 1
                                                                     else 0
                                                                     end
                                                               )
                                                       else 0
                                                       end
          end as MaxConsecutiveIncreases
from c
    left join c as c2
        on c2.rn between c.rn-5 and c.rn
group by c.snapshot_date
        ,c.customer_id
        ,c.Number
        ,c.ConsecutiveIncreases
order by 1
```

Output:

```
+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------------------+
| snapshot_date | customer_id | Number | MaxConsecutiveIncreases |
+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------------------+
| 2014-01-01    |       12342 |      0 |                       0 |
| 2014-02-01    |       12342 |     15 |                       1 |
| 2014-03-01    |       12342 |     45 |                       2 |
| 2014-04-01    |       12342 |      0 |                       2 |
| 2014-05-01    |       12342 |     15 |                       2 |
| 2014-06-01    |       12342 |     45 |                       2 |
| 2014-07-01    |       12342 |     75 |                       3 |
| 2014-08-01    |       12342 |    105 |                       4 |
| 2014-09-01    |       12342 |    135 |                       5 |
| 2014-10-01    |       12342 |      0 |                       4 |
| 2014-11-01    |       12342 |      0 |                       3 |
| 2014-12-01    |       12342 |      0 |                       2 |
| 2015-01-01    |       12342 |      0 |                       1 |
| 2015-02-01    |       12342 |      0 |                       0 |
| 2015-03-01    |       12342 |      0 |                       0 |
| 2015-04-01    |       12342 |      0 |                       0 |
+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i think as at snapshot_date-2014-04-01, Maxconsecutiveincrease should be 2 because 02 times increase in 'number' column in 06 preceding rows. And please share more about your logic, because it is new to me

Comment: And one more things @iamdave. My table has approx 1.000.000 rows, so that will trouble if i use recursive cte cause temporary data is very large?

Comment: @trato  Updated my script.  Because of that you are looking to do, I cannot as yet see a way to do this in an efficient set based manner so it will always be slow.